# Linux kernel : linked list - runtime memory allocation

Tags: linux, list, kernel

Upon ioctl from user space to kernel module I want to insert an entry to a list.
This can happen forever, every 2msec.

Upon interrupt handled in the kernel module (every ~2msec), the first item is pulled from the list.

Can you please tell if kernel list dynamically allocating memory? I want to avoid runtime allocation + free.

Is there an alternative without runtime allocation?

Comment: If you are talking about double-linked lists defined by `struct list_head`, then they doesn't perform automatic allocation. (You could easily deduce that by looking at their API in [include/linux/list.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h)). If you want to not allocate/deallocate elements in the interrupt, then you could preallocate some number of elements.

Comment: Read a Linux Driver development book, you need to familiarise yourself with fundamentals in order to be able to write a kernel module.

Comment: Tsyvarev - Thank you for your  reply. Got it. But the items I insert into the list should be allocated. Is there an API for pool from which I can take objects and return them later ?

Comment: There is general-purpose pool `kmalloc`/`kfree`. You could also create allocator for your own objects, `kmem_cache`. If you need fixed-sized pool, then you can easily implement it by placing available elements into the list.